# Silverlight 4: Is it possible to bind ListBoxItem's width and height property?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've got following issue:

I've got a ListBox which items are lain on Canvas. I would like to be able to xamly position its elements. The ItemContainerStyle looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ElementContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
  <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding BoundingBox.Y}" />
  <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding BoundingBox.X}" />
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding BoundingBox.Width}" />
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding BoundingBox.Height}" />
  ...
</Style>
```

With such a style SL crashes with InnerException's message:

> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot set read-only property

Why's that read-only property? If I put regular values there (not data bounded) it runs well, except - this is not what I wanted.

I was looking forward to new features for SL4 (like ability to bind to Width and Height properties), but it seems that such a trick still can't be done?

It works fine in WPF..

Anyone can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a Binding to the Setter.Value property is not supported in Silverlight. Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/07/one-more-platform-difference-more-or-less-tamed-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better.aspx) for a workaround, which uses an attached property to create/assign the binding when the Style is applied to an instance.